# Oracle Apex and Sharepoint

Tags: oracle, sharepoint, oracle-apex

I have been asked to do some on a topic I know very little about and need some help getting pointed in the right direction.

Questions I am looking into are:

1. What are SharePoint's (2003 and 2010) data-management capabilities relative to those of Oracle APEX?
2. To what degree can Oracle and SharePoint speak to each other so that data in one can be imported into or read by the other?

Questions I have on this:
1. Is there enough information there to even start anwsering those two questions?
2. What follow up questions should I ask?
3. My understanding is APEX is an application (like  microsoft access) and Sharepoint is more a framework. Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

> 1. What are SharePoint's (2003 and 2010) data-management capabilities relative to those of Oracle APEX?

[Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/pages/default.aspx) is a document management system from Microsoft, so it is an application that allows you to store, retrieve and share files with permissions etc.  It is [not a database](http://chriswoodill.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/sharepoint-is-not-database.html).

[Oracle APEX](http://apex.oracle.com) is a tool for building web applications over an Oracle database.  It is not a document management system, nor is it (APEX) a database.  You could **build** a document management system using Oracle APEX and the Oracle database, given enough time, but it isn't one.  You can store documents directly in the Oracle database using the BLOB data type.

Really this question is comparing apples and oranges!

> 2. To what degree can Oracle and SharePoint speak to each other so
>   that data in one can be imported into or read by the other?

Sharepoint provides [various APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/24/deciding-which-sharepoint-2010-api-to-use-jim-crowley.aspx) to enable other software to manage documents using Sharepoint.  An Oracle APEX (or any other type of) application could call these APIs.